# Resolving ViewModel's commands from Controller? (PRISM)

Tags: command, prism, viewmodel, icommand

How would I go about resolving a ViewModel's commands from a controller?

Right now I'm having to dependency inject the UnityContainer into the ViewModel via constructor, and resolve the ICommand with a string. I don't really want to have to pass the container to my viewmodel, and would prefer to keep it in my controller.

These are just snippets, not the whole thing. Not that they're that complex of classes yet though while I try to learn.

---

ViewModel

```
    private ICommand loadedCommand;
    public ICommand LoadedCommand
    {
        get { return loadedCommand; }
        set
        {
            loadedCommand = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.LoadedCommand);
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
    {
      LoadedCommand = container.Resolve<ICommand>("LoadedCommand")
    }
```

---

*Controller*

```
    DelegateCommand LoadedCommand;
    new DelegateCommand(() => ViewLoaded());
```

---

*Controller*

```
        Container.RegisterInstance<ICommand>("LoadedCommand", LoadedCommand);
```

I don't even know if I'm going about this the right way. I'm sort of diving into everything at once, with Prism and Dependency Injection and mvvm(with controllers) being relatively new to me.

Comment: Should the controller own the ICommand's of the ViewModel? I would think yes, since I am told the ViewModel should not have any logic in it. How do I get the Controller's DelegateCommand's injected into the ViewModel, when every ICommand is different? Do I create an interface for every Command? Ideally I'd like to create the Commands in their own class in my module.

Comment: I learned that I can add the [Dependency] attribute to the LoadedCommand property like this.

[Dependency("LoadedCommand")]

And now I can get rid of having the ViewModel having to know about a  UnityContainer.

Is this ideal? Is there another way I should think about doing this?

Comment: I am still seeking an answer to this question. In the simplest of terms, I want to know the proper way to "how to set the code in ViewModel ICommands from the Controller"

I've seen many posts by HiTech Magic talking about this, but he doesn't really discuss how to do this. I don't know if it needs to be dependency injected, if it needs to just be set by accessing the properties directly in the controller.

I bought "Dependency Injection in .NET" to hopefully find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be entirely sure about your question. But the way I understand commanding in MVVM is: You have the view and instead of click events you use command objects.

The reason is, that click events go to the codebehind, and using command instead you have the ability to transfer the logic to the viewmodel.

The view uses binding to connect to the viewmodel.

So a short example:
(Usage):

```
<Element Property="{Binding PropertyNameInTheViewModel}" />
```

(Example):

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
```

Then of course make the View's datacontext to the viewmodel. Example (done in the codebehind):

```
public partial class View : Window
{
   public View(ViewModel vm)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = vm:
   }
}
```

In the viewmodel

```
public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

#region constructor
public Viewmodel()
{
    ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(ButtonClick);
}
#endregion

private void ButtonClick()
{
    // handle the click
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'controller'. The design pattern as I've learned, goes View -> ViewModel -> Model. And use dependency injection in to the view constructor in order to pass the viewmodel. Personally I'm learning MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) instead of Unity.

Comment: I've been trying to use the MVCVM pattern, which I've learned from HiTechMagic on stackoverflow. Basically the controller creates both the view and thewmodel, assigning the viewmodel as the datacontext of the view and initializing and changing all the values for ViewModel. The viewmodel does nothing but presents information to be consumed by the view.

And therein lies my problem... do I just assign all the values in the controller, or is there a more clean, encapsulated way of doing it? That is basically what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Personally I think putting an extra "controller" in is not the right way to go. Simply because the purpose of the controller (as they are describing) is to be the middle man between view and vm. But that is not necessary because you can just use bindings... Why go the extra step? And if you are using Dependency Injection with Prism, you go from the viewmodel/module and then register the view with a region.

Comment: In summary: (in my opinion) I wouldn't use that approach.
And in prism/with DI I would define the commands in the viewmodel - no need to pass them in a constructor.

Comment: Well... from what I've been working on with one of my programs trying to learn this stuff, it seems to work fairly well. I'm still unsure about the whole way of assigning the controllers and stuff... but the view is still being databound to the viewmodel. The controller isn't the middleman... but more like an encompasing entity that marriages them together. Instead of the view or the viewmodel creating the other and thus knowing about the other beyond a simple agreement of what they both need, the controller worries about that instead. And the controller handles all the other logic as well.

Comment: Ok. But in Prism, you can compose the program in modules. Think of little packages of functionality... Then these modules individually use mvvm, where they have a view/viewmodel/model. The whole program then use a socalled [bootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430868(v=pandp.40).aspx) (either mefbootstrapper or unitybootstrapper or a custombootstrapper) to register/setup the container and the catalogs.

So in this startup process the program will discover the modules. And it all uses reflection and lazy instantiation (which simply means instantiate only when needed).